# JSP JSTL funciton fn:split is not working properly

Tags: java, jsp, split, jstl

Today, I come across one issue and need your help to fix it.

I am trying to split the string using **JSTL** `fn:split` *function* that is likewise,

```
<c:set var="stringArrayName" value="${fn:split(element, '~$')}" />
```

**Actual String :-** `"abc~$pqr$xyz"`

**Expected Result :-**

```
abc 
pqr$xyz
```

only 2-string part expecting, but it gives

```
abc
pqr
xyz
```

here, total 3-string parts returning, which is wrong.

**NOTE :-** I have added `<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%> at the top of JSP.`

*any help really appreciates!!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSTL split not work like the Java split you can check the difference from the code source :

[org.apache.taglibs.standard.functions.Functions.split](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/taglibs/standard/1.1.2/org/apache/taglibs/standard/functions/Functions.java#Functions.split%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29)

```
public static String[] split(String input, String delimiters) {
    String[] array;
    if (input == null) {
        input = "";
    }
    if (input.length() == 0) {
        array = new String[1];
        array[0] = "";
        return array;
    }

    if (delimiters == null) {
        delimiters = "";
    }

    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(input, delimiters);
    int count = tok.countTokens();
    array = new String[count];
    int i = 0;
    while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
        array[i++] = tok.nextToken();
    }
    return array;
}
```

[java.lang.String.split](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.split%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29)

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
}
```

So it's clearly that `fn:split` use `StringTokenizer`

```
    ...
    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(input, delimiters);
    int count = tok.countTokens();
    array = new String[count];
    int i = 0;
    while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
        array[i++] = tok.nextToken();
    }
    ...
```

Not like `java.lang.String.split` which use [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

```
return Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
//-----------------------^
```

from the [StringTokenizer documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) it says :

> Constructs a string tokenizer for the specified string. **The characters
>   in the delim argument are the delimiters for separating tokens**.
>   Delimiter characters themselves will not be treated as tokens.

#### How `fn:split` exactly work?

It split on each character in the delimiter, in your case you have two characters `~` and `$` so if your string is `abc~$pqr$xyz` it will split it like this :

```
abc~$pqr$xyz
   ^^   ^
```

1st split :

```
abc
$pqr$xyz
```

2nd split :

```
abc
pqr$xyz
```

3rd split :

```
abc
pqr
xyz
```

---

**Solution**

> use split in your Servlet instead of JSTL

for example :

```
String[] array = "abc~$pqr$xyz".split("~\\$");
```

Comment: Thanks @YCF_L, it's works now by using Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\~\\$");

Comment: @vishalgajera you can just use split like this `String[] array = "abc~$pqr$xyz".split("~\\$");`